# How do you control build order of sibling dependent targets with msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-target

In my project, I have two import statements:

```
<Import Project="<TransformConfigLocation>" />
<Import Project="<PackageLocation>" />
```

Each target has a property group defined like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
        $(BuildDependsOn);
        TransformConfig
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
        $(BuildDependsOn);
        Package
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I would like to guarantee that TransformConfig always runs before Package.  I do not control either of the dependent targets and would prefer not to have to edit them explicitly because those edits would be wiped any time I updated those targets via NuGet.  The Package target consistently runs first which is undesirable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that the order of the Imports *does* matter.  For more detail on why, see @Seva Titov's answer and our follow up conversation.

I highly recommend http://amzn.com/0735645248 for a thorough analysis on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Within the project a build order is guaranteed to follow MSBuild [target build order rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx). There is no race conditions here, everything is serialized. A quote from the link above:

> ```
> <Target Name="Serve" DependsOnTargets="Chop;Cook" />
> ```
>
> tells MSBuild that the Serve target depends on the Chop target and the
>   Cook target. MSBuild runs the Chop target, and then runs the Cook
>   target before it runs the Serve target.

Note that if some other target that gets executed before "Serve" has any of the Chop/Cook targets as their dependencies or had listed them in BeforeTargets/AfterTargets, that might affect the order. For example, if you have this set of targets:

```
 <Target Name="One" DependsOnTargets="Two;Three" />
 <Target Name="Two" DependsOnTargets="TargetB" />
 <Target Name="Three" DependsOnTargets="TargetA;TargetB;" />
```

and you build "One", then the build order would be as follows:

```
TargetB
Two
TargetA
// skip TargetB because it was already run
Three
One
```

So, in your case, assuming TargetB is not listed as dependency of any previous targets, $(BuildDependsOn) list gets executed in the order targets are listed there, which would be  `...;TargetA;TargetB`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand those rules and they are clear.  However, I don't see how your answer is applicable to my situation.  My project file has two import statements and does not specify a DependsOnTargets attribute for its primary target.  The two imported target files contain targets with BuildDependsOn sections as mentioned in the OP.  I do not have control over those target files other than the order in which I import them in my project file.  How do I guarantee the order in which those targets are run?

Comment: I have updated the OP with more realistic target names to hopefully clarify the problem.

Comment: @DPeden, I might not have said it clearly. You have defined or modified `$(BuildDependsOn)` property. This property, when expanded will have a value something like `"...;TransformConfig;Package"`. The property $(BuildDependsOn) is likely used in a target like this: <Target Name="Build" DependsOn="$(BuildDependsOn)" />. Does it make it clear how this is related to what I said in answer?

Comment: Yeah, after playing with it a bit more and consulting @Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi's excellent book (see Target Injection in http://amzn.com/0735645248), it basically does come down to the order of the Imports.

Comment: My answer technically answers the question I asked and thus I marked it as such.  However, I +1'd yours because it contains useful info.  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @DPeden, your answer is not technically correct. The order of execution of dependent targets might or might not follow order the dependents are specified in DependsOnTargets list. If one of the previously executed target has one of the targets listed there as a dependents or BeforeTarget or AfterTarger, then the order does not matter -- see more details in my answer.